# Database modelling (mongoDB)

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, database-design, mongoose-schema

I am trying to model a database for a fitness app. Currently the 4 main entities are as follows:

| Exercise | User | Workout | UserWorkout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id | id |
| name | email | name | userId (*fk*) |
| body_part | name | description | workoutId *(fk)* |
| category | password | level | date |
|  | age | exerciseIds (*fk*) | time_taken |

The app will have default workouts as well as default exercises.

---

**I would like the user to be able to add their own custom workouts/exercises that only they can see (in addition to the default ones) but I'm not sure on how to best structure the data?**

---

Answer (score 1):

Kris, MongoDB is a schemaless database, what makes it really flexible when it comes down to data modelling. There are different ways of achieving what you described, the one I would recommend would be adding nested documents to the user document if they belong to it. You would have something like this:

```
User {
  firstName: ...,
  lastName: ...,
  age: ...,
  weight: ...,
  exercises: [
     // User's exercise objects
  ],
  workout: [
     // User's workout objects
  ],
}
```

This way you can easily have access to information related to the user and avoid using expensive operations like **$lookup** or querying the database multiple times.

To handle the default exercises/workouts you can have a property in the respective objects like `isDefault: true`.

Comment: Hi Rafael, thanks for your response. One reason why I did not embed the documents was that I would have to repeat the default exercises/workouts for each user. That is a lot of the same data.